# Запрет добавления черновика товара в заказ через админку

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Магазин работает на WP+WooCommerce.   Бывает, что покупатель, после создания заказа, в телефонном режиме просит добавить товар в его заказ. Менеджер через админку добавляет этот товар в нужный заказ. Ассортимент товаров довольно большой и часто меняется. Соответственно некоторые новые товары имеют статус "черновик". Требуется запретить менеджеру добавлять товары с этим статусом в заказы, но при этом, чтобы у менеджера оставалось право создавать и редактировать черновики.

Т.е. по сути, мне программно бы убрать товар со статусом " черновик" из поиска при добавлении товаров в админке на странице заказа.

Comment: По умолчанию нельзя ни изменить состав заказа ни тем более добавить черновик в новый заказ. Ищи проблему в своих плагинах.

Comment: Почему же нельзя? Заказ "в обработке", админ может менять любые данные в заказе. В т.ч. товары.

Comment: Потому что нельзя. Специально проверил на голом WC прежде чем писать. https://i.imgur.com/39K6ClJ.jpeg. Новый заказ из админки тоже проверял - не находит черновики.

Comment: Прошу прощения, статус "на удержании" (on_hold_order). Этот статус скриптом устанавливается по умолчанию. И эти заказы редактировать можно. Но вопрос не в этом. Вопрос: как исключить добавление админом именно черновиков.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bxdotAZ

Comment: В холде состав редактируется, да. Но черновики не находятся https://i.imgur.com/6OhkcR0.jpeg

Comment: Спасибо за потраченные время (у меня нет возможности прогонять голый wc). Буду разбираться с плагинами.

Comment: Погонять ВП можно в песочнице. Например [тут](https://tastewp.com/s/freesite)

Answer (score 1):

Варианты выхода из ситуации:

1. **Запретить добавлять**
2. **Перед добавлением** смотреть статус товара
3. **Перед записью или отправкой** проверять статус всех товаров
4. Написать костыль. И тут быстрого ответа не будет.

Единственное могу подсказать, что есть хук woocommerce_new_order_item, который вроде отрабатывает и по клику добавить товар в ордер в админке (но это не точно) - находится в файле wc-order-item-functions.php .
Меня на него вывел поиск dropdown-wrapper в JS файлах, который в свою очередь  вызывал через аякс wc_add_order_item.
Через него, с горем пополам можно внедрить доп. проверку и исключать товары не опубликованные из массива. То есть данный хук срабатывает уже после добавления товаров в заказ (судя по коду) и надо повторно, самому обойти ещё раз заказ и удалить из него те товары, что не опубликованы.
То есть куда копать есть, но готового решения, увы не предложу.

У меня добавления в заказы через админку запрещены от слова совсем.

Причина в том, что часть людей скажут: "Вы меня не поняли, не то добавили", а время потеряно, а иногда и товар поехал...

**ЗАЧЕМ?**

Comment: Вопрос "Зачем?" - это первый вопрос, который у меня постоянно возникает при очередных правках. Но, такова воля заказчика. А мой вопрос решился через фильтр "woocommerce_json_search_found_products". Т.е. я пошёл по пути №2.